# Contact framework crashing app while appending phone number

Tags: swift, contacts

While trying to update an existing contact I am getting sigabrt error "**A property was not requested when contact was fetched**".

```
var cntct= existingContact.mutableCopy() as! CNMutableContact

let phone= CNLabledValue(label:CNLabelPhoneNumberMain, value:"786967655566") 

cntct.phoneNumbers.append(phone)
```

Comment: Errors says you are accessing a property which was not requested with keysToFetch when fetched. More about this here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontact/1403210-iskeyavailable

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling for a few hours with my own related issue: I needed to add a birthday to a contact with swift. With some research, trial and error, and troubleshooting, here's what I came up with:

```
    var contactStore = CNContactStore()
    var contactx:CNMutableContact = CNMutableContact()

    let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingName("\(firstnamefield.text!) \(lastnamefield.text!) \(suffixfield.text!)") // searches for contacts matching the inserted name (inputted by the user as first name, then last name, then any suffixes).

    let toFetch = [CNContactBirthdayKey]
    do{
        var contacts = try contactStore.unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(
            predicate, keysToFetch: toFetch)

        print(contacts)

        for contact in contacts {

            let birthday = NSDateComponents()
            birthday.year = Int(yearfield.text!)! // sets the birthday year
            birthday.month = Int(monthfield.text!)! // sets the birthday month
            birthday.day = Int(dayfield.text!)! // sets the birthday day

            let mutableContact = contact.mutableCopy() as! CNMutableContact
            mutableContact.birthday = birthday // sets the contacts found with predicate search to having the birthday set above.

            let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
            saveRequest.updateContact(mutableContact)
            try contactStore.executeSaveRequest(saveRequest)
```

Obviously, this adds a birthday instead of a phone number, but you can use the exact same principles (predicate search, for contact in contacts) for adding a phone number; just change what happens inside the for contact in contacts loop! I hope this helps you, sorry that you didn't get a response earlier.

Basically, you can change what's inside of the contact loop to

```
let phone= CNLabledValue(label:CNLabelPhoneNumberMain, value:"786967655566") 

cntct.phoneNumbers.append(phone)
```

and you should have a phone number adding process.

Comment: @Aslam I hope this helps you; let me know if I can help you convert this to adding phone numbers!